# Possible water hammer under kitchen sink

Tags: kitchen-sink, water-hammer

My husband and I installed a new kitchen faucet a few days ago (we are not plumbers).  Ever since then, when you shut off the hot water (or when the dishwasher runs), it makes a banging noise. From our internet research, it sounds like a water hammer.  There seems to be all sorts of solutions on the net, but some even contradict each other.  We did try draining the air out of the pipes, but even that had very different methods for how to do it, so not sure if we did it correctly.

Note, before we installed the new faucet, there was never a sound when you shut the hot water off.

Any thoughts on what to do? THank you

Comment: How old is the plumbing? "Newer" (like, in the last few decades at least, I think) should have stubs to absorb the shock and reduce or prevent water hammer. If those exist and have sufficient air in them, it should have prevented the noise. That said, you can always install a "hammer arrestor" at the water line hookup; it's a small cylinder that is essentially a shock absorber for the water. More info about the situation would help: more details about how exactly the removal and installation went, what the configuration of the water lines are, and what contradictions you're concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

A loose washer on the hot water shutoff can also cause a hammer..

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.